# chef-client creates a folder instead of file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've cookbook with following structure:

```
cookbook
  |
  files
  | |__default
  |    |__filebeat
  |       |__filebeat.yml
  recipes
      |__filebeat.rb
```

I need to copy file *filebeat.yml* from *files/default/filebeat* by chef-client with following code located in **files/resipes/filebeat.rb**:

```
cookbook_file "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml" do
    source "filebeat/filebeat.yml"
    force_unlink true
    owner  "root"
    group "root"
    mode   "0755"
    action :create
    ignore_failure true
end
```

After run *chef-client* instead of creation **filebeat.yml** I've got the folder with name *filebeat.yml* at */etc/filebeat/*. Whats wrong here?

After run chef-client on a host

```
root@wauitest-20002-001-prod:~# ls -l /etc/filebeat
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 27 07:32 filebeat.yml
```

Comment: Might not be related, but why is the recipe in `files/recipes/`? Chef client will pick up recipes from `recipes/` directory and not `files/`. Is there a different `<cookbook_name>/recipes/filebeat.rb` (which might actually be running)?

Comment: Thank you! The same issue after file tree changed

Comment: How do you run the recipe? Can you update the question with output from `chef-client` run?